# How to read Driver Property Extended configuration Ids in WMI using C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, wmi

I am using WMI in C# to retrieve properties of Windows devices using the code below.
However I can't find a property of **ManagementObject** that contains the **Extended configuration Ids** that are visible in the Windows Device Manager window though. Any idea how to access that property value by code?

```c#
    ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator driversEnumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
    while (driversEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        ManagementObject driver = (ManagementObject)driversEnumerator.Current;
        var props = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (PropertyData prop in driver.Properties)
        {
            props.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value);
        }
    }
```

[image: Device Manager Details Extended configuration Ids]

Comment: you need call [`CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_devnode_propertyw) with [`DEVPKEY_Device_ExtendedConfigurationIds`](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.16299.0/shared/devpkey.h#L157)

Comment: @RbMm Thank you. Any idea if there's an equivalent C# function?

Comment: this is winapi function and not related to any language